# Spring Boot application not receiving data from database once deployed to tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, azure-sql-database, tomcat8

I've created a simple Spring Boot application that queries an Azure SQL DB. I'm able to run everything locally but once I deploy to tomcat all my DB transactions are null/empty.

When I look into the logs I can see the generated SQL query and it looks correct. I've even ran the generated SQL query in VSCode and it's returning the correct information.

The app is connecting to the DB but for some reason it's not able to get any data. I'm thinking it's a dependency issue but I everything looks correct to the best of my knowledge.

I'm running tomcat version - 8.5

**builde.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.something'
version = '1.1'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

war {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.something.application'
    }
}

ext {
    set('azureVersion', '2.0.8')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:7.0.0.jre8'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-web', version: '2.+'
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-core', version: '2.+'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-boot-bom:${azureVersion}"
    }
}
```

**CustomerEntity.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int c_id;
    private String username;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
}
```

**CustomerRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.data.Customer;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT u FROM Customer u WHERE u.c_id = ?1")
    Customer getCustomer(int c_id);
}
```

**Datasource Config**

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(username).password(AzureSQLPwd).url(url)
            .driverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").build();
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

Comment: Are you certain that the application is connecting to the same database in each case? It might be worth checking the URL (and username and password) being used to create your `DataSource` bean.

Comment: Yes. I only have a single database I can connect to. I even printed the pwd out and it’s correct.

Comment: I think you should use Integer instead int as a Customer id. Try this, please